# Prevent duplicate form submit with jQuery Mobile Ajax Navigation (without disabling ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post, jquery-mobile

In my form if you click Submit twice quickly enough I get two successful form ajax posts. How can I stop duplicate posts?

From what I can tell

1. User clicks submit
2. Ajax post sent
3. User clicks submit (completed and valid form)
4. Ajax post sent
5. Ajax response received
6. Page refreshed with empty (new empty form - requires values)
7. Ajax response received
8. Page refreshed with empty (new empty form - requires values)

The form is sent twice, I create two items.

There are similarly named questions but they relate to disabling validation or disabling ajax. Ajax, jquery validation and server side validation (Post-Redirect-Get in MVC) are working just fine for me.

Just to be clear I'm using [jQuery Mobile's Ajax navigation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html) so *I'm not writing any ajax*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I have now is:

```
$(document).on('submit', "form", null, function (e) {
    $(this).find("input:submit")
    .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    // the following is optional, arguably unnecessary
    .delay(2000)
    .queue(function (next) { $(this).removeAttr('disabled'); next(); });
});
```

(Updated to work in webkit)

The delay is just in case something goes wrong. In reality the form should get replaced and the replacement will not be disabled.

Better suggestions welcome.

Comment: Rather than depending on a delay, why not re-initialize the submit button when the AJAX response is received? You could setup a generic `.ajaxSuccess()` handler that runs for all AJAX requests or you could add the JS to the AJAX response.

Comment: The DOM re-initialises as the post returns a redirect on success. The delay should only run out on timeout/error rather than ajax success... perhaps on `.ajaxError()` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document.body)
.on("input:submit", "click", function () {
  var $this = $(this);

  if ( !$this.is(".submitting") ) {
    $this.addClass("submitting");

    $.ajax({ url: "etc..."})
    .done(function () {
      // success callback;
    })
    .fail(function () {
      // error callback;
    })
    .always(function () {
      $this.removeClass("submitting");
    })
  }
});
```

This has the nice side effect that you can modify the style of the submit button with the `submitting` CSS class. You could additionally/alternatively disable it and re-enable it in the `always` callback.

Comment: I want to avoid writing the ajax call, instead hoping to use the standard post and let jquery intercept it and run it as an ajax call

Comment: @KCD I see. You can catch the `submit` event in just the same way and just disable the submit button.

Comment: I found disabling the `input:submit` button on its submit event sometimes posted the submit (firefox) sometimes blocked it (webkit). Updated my answer to catch the event when it bubbles to the form

Comment: @KCD You can also set a value, maybe `$("form").data("submitting", true)` and only post the form as long as the value is not yet set. This is the same approach as setting a CSS class.